# Retrieve the last row inserted in the DB

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, jdbc

I am developing an online banking application, and this is 1 part where I am stuck.

->Users are shown a form on an HTML page to enter their details, to create an account.

->The details are then entered into a MySQL database, and the user is redirected to a JSP page, where he should be shown his account number (generated automatically using MySQL auto-increment feature), and a secret 4 digit pin(generated randomly for every user, not by auto-increment).

The code sinppet from my servlet's doPost() method to insert values in DB and redirection to JSP is here-

```
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inb", "root", "root");

//The user's password has to be converted into a salted hash before storing in the database.
String hashed_password=CreateDigest.getPasswordDigest(request.getParameter("password"));

PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into inb.users values (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        ps.setString(1, request.getParameter("name1"));
        ps.setString(2, request.getParameter("name2"));
        ps.setString(3, request.getParameter("name3"));
        ps.setString(4, request.getParameter("dob"));
        ps.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age")));
        ps.setString(6, request.getParameter("email"));
        ps.setString(7, request.getParameter("mobnum"));
        ps.setString(8, request.getParameter("address1"));
        ps.setString(9, request.getParameter("address2"));
        ps.setString(10, request.getParameter("pannum"));
        ps.setString(11, request.getParameter("aadhar"));
        ps.setString(12, hashed_password);
        ps.setString(13, request.getParameter("acc_bal"));
        ps.setInt(14, pin);

            int i=ps.executeUpdate();


    //Check if records have been actually been inserted or not.
        if (i>0)    {
            response.sendRedirect("AccountOpened.jsp");
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now, this is the JSP code to display the account no. and pin of the user-
(last_acc_no and last_pin are static variables in my Servlet class, which I created to hold the last inserted account no and pin.)

```
<% 
String acc_no=CreateAccount.last_acc_No;
int pin=CreateAccount.last_pin;
%>
<h3>Congratulations ! Your account has been created.</h3>.
<br/><br/>
Your Account Number Is : <b> <%= acc_no %> </b>
<br/><br/>
Your Secret PIN No. Is : <b> <%= pin %> </b>
```

Now, I want to retrieve the account_no and pin of the last inserted user, so that I can show it on the JSP page. And I am not able to figure out a method for that.

Comment: `static` variables in servlet class is **bad** ! Next thing is don't use sriptlets in JSP ! A question , why do you use `redirect()` instead of `RequestDispatcher` ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot what's worse: OP creates the database connection manually instead of using a Database Connection Pool and there's no difference between Model and Controller in this application, with also shows a lack of knowledge on developing layered applications for maintenance purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inb", "root", "root");

//The user's password has to be converted into a salted hash before storing in the database.
String hashed_password=CreateDigest.getPasswordDigest(request.getParameter("password"));

PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into inb.users values (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setString(1, request.getParameter("name1"));
        ps.setString(2, request.getParameter("name2"));
        ps.setString(3, request.getParameter("name3"));
        ps.setString(4, request.getParameter("dob"));
        ps.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age")));
        ps.setString(6, request.getParameter("email"));
        ps.setString(7, request.getParameter("mobnum"));
        ps.setString(8, request.getParameter("address1"));
        ps.setString(9, request.getParameter("address2"));
        ps.setString(10, request.getParameter("pannum"));
        ps.setString(11, request.getParameter("aadhar"));
        ps.setString(12, hashed_password);
        ps.setString(13, request.getParameter("acc_bal"));
        ps.setInt(14, pin);

            int i=ps.executeUpdate(); 


    //Check if records have been actually been inserted or not.
            ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
            request.setAttribute("id", id);
            request.setAttribute("pin", pin);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("AccountOpened.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in your jsp page:

```
<h3>Congratulations ! Your account has been created.</h3>.
<br/><br/>
Your Account Number Is : <b> <%= request.getAttribute("id")%> </b>
<br/><br/>
Your Secret PIN No. Is : <b> <%= request.getAttribute("pin") %> </b>
```

Comment: @TheNewIdiot- Thanx for the info you gave me, I didn't know that. But can you please tell me what are the disadvantages of using static variables in a servlet, and why shouldn't we use scriptlets in a JSP page??

Comment: @plutonium1991, those are request scope attributes. Servelt one may not be thread safe. Check scopes and servlet thread safe attributes. Aslo do not forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `Return SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in your `t-sql`?

Is `int i` returning the account number - it should be.  That way you don't have to worry about it being the topmost entry in your database.  It's dangerous to strictly say you just want the last record that was created. User A and user B could be creating an account around the same time and get tangled/crossed account information.  Once you have the accountNumber for "int i" then you shouldn't have a problem re-grabbing this information from the database?

Does this help?

Comment: @fenix- int i only returns the no. of records inserted in the DB, which is most probably 1. This is not the account no. And I simply want to get the account no and pin from the database, to show it to the user. Won't a bank give a user's acc. no to him??

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza- I am a student learning java technologies, not a professional like you. And this project is a part of my summer training.